# Can't get any SMART or temperature data from HDDs

Tags: monitoring, hard-drive, smart

I have a PC with recently installed Gigabyte GA-X79-UD5 MB. 
I've encountered some weird problem with getting SMART data or temperature for HDDs. Every single tool I've tried in Windows 7 just can't get any data (HDTune, AIDA64...).
I was suspecting that SMART feature is disabled in BIOS but it's seems like there is no such option in BIOS settings. I've even tried to update BIOS but still no luck.

Same issue with both controllers on that MB (Intel and Marvell). It seems unlikely that both controllers end up with exact same issue.
Both controllers are working in AHCI mode.

Is there anythig that can interfere with getting SMART ant temp data from HDDs? Or is there any way to check that it's actuall MB issue?

Is it even possible that it is hardware issue since all HDDs seems to work normal despite the fact that I can't get any temperature or SMART data from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check if the WMI class exist and that you can retrieve the WMI data for the drives. If not, that may be a good place to start. You can use a tool such as Microsoft WMI Code Creator, and browse/display WMI information.  Select the root\WMI namespace, and the MSStorageDriver_ATAPISmartData class.  Select all of the properties, and click Execute Code.

[image]

Microsoft WMI Code Creator download:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

Answer (score 2):

I've found a reason of such strange behaviour and it's an obvious bug in Intel RSTe driver. Actually I'm not the first one who found out that.

I've found some discussions of the matter on Intel and AIDA64 forums:
[Intel Forum](http://communities.intel.com/message/157969), [AIDA64 Forum](http://forums.aida64.com/index.php?/topic/625-aida64-v2001754-cannot-report-the-smart-infos-of-hard-disks-on-intel-x79-chipset/)

The thing is that Intel RSTe driver is "stuck" in RAID no matter of real MB settings and it's result in issues with SMART and temperature reading as well as BSODs from time to time. Right now I'm using standart Microsoft AHCI driver and waiting an answer from Intel support.